# Struts2 simple Application not executing

Tags: java, struts2, bootstrapping, xml-configuration

```
Unable to load configuration. - bean - wsjar:file:/C:/Users/xx/IBM/rationalsdp/workspace/workspace1/Struts2Int/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-gxp-plugin-2.3.15.3.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:8:162
```

I am unable to execute simple Struts 2.x application.I have tried solutions from all other Struts2 posts that are related to this but could not fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The library `struts2-gxp-plugin-2.3.15.3.jar` is deployed with the application. But it should be removed from the library set if you don't use GXP in your application and this plugin. For details aboult a plugin you could read a related plugin documentation.