# Dispatcher initialization failed with Struts2

Tags: java, struts2, tomcat7

I'm building my first web app with Struts2. I don't find the error (well, I don't think I made errors, in fact) but Tomcat gives me always 404...

I post the log here for you to suggest me a solution. But it didn't help me a lot, it only says that he has failed to load configuration or bean. I really don't know.

Log:

```
mag 11, 2014 12:13:45 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
Informazioni: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/lib/i386;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\eclipse;;.
mag 11, 2014 12:13:46 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
Avvertenza: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Struts2Starter' did not find a matching property.
mag 11, 2014 12:13:47 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
Informazioni: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
mag 11, 2014 12:13:47 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
Informazioni: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
mag 11, 2014 12:13:47 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
Informazioni: Initialization processed in 2878 ms
mag 11, 2014 12:13:47 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
Informazioni: Starting service Catalina
mag 11, 2014 12:13:47 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
Informazioni: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
mag 11, 2014 12:13:48 AM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
Informazioni: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [336] milliseconds.
mag 11, 2014 12:13:58 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider info
Informazioni: Parsing configuration file [struts-default.xml]
mag 11, 2014 12:13:59 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider info
Informazioni: Parsing configuration file [struts-plugin.xml]
mag 11, 2014 12:14:00 AM org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher error
Grave: Dispatcher initialization failed
Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/C:/Users/Dario/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Struts2Starter/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-gxp-plugin-2.3.16.3.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:8:162
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:70)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:445)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:489)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4775)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5452)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: Unable to load bean: type:org.apache.struts2.views.gxp.inject.InjectedObjectContainer class:org.apache.struts2.views.gxp.inject.InjectedObjectContainer - bean - jar:file:/C:/Users/Dario/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Struts2Starter/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-gxp-plugin-2.3.16.3.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:8:162
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:245)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.register(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:102)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:234)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.views.gxp.inject.InjectedObjectContainer
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:152)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:216)
    ... 19 more

mag 11, 2014 12:14:00 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
Grave: Exception starting filter struts2
Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/C:/Users/Dario/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Struts2Starter/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-gxp-plugin-2.3.16.3.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:8:162
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:501)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4775)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5452)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/C:/Users/Dario/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Struts2Starter/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-gxp-plugin-2.3.16.3.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:8:162
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:70)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:445)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:489)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: Unable to load bean: type:org.apache.struts2.views.gxp.inject.InjectedObjectContainer class:org.apache.struts2.views.gxp.inject.InjectedObjectContainer - bean - jar:file:/C:/Users/Dario/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Struts2Starter/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-gxp-plugin-2.3.16.3.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:8:162
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:245)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.register(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:102)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:234)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.views.gxp.inject.InjectedObjectContainer
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:152)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:216)
    ... 19 more

mag 11, 2014 12:14:00 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
Grave: Error filterStart
mag 11, 2014 12:14:00 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
Grave: Context [/Struts2Starter] startup failed due to previous errors
mag 11, 2014 12:14:00 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
Informazioni: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
mag 11, 2014 12:14:00 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
Informazioni: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
mag 11, 2014 12:14:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
Informazioni: Server startup in 13236 ms
```

After removing gxp plugin jar, the error I get is:

```
mag 11, 2014 7:06:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
Informazioni: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/lib/i386;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\eclipse;;.
mag 11, 2014 7:06:39 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
Avvertenza: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Struts2Starter' did not find a matching property.
mag 11, 2014 7:06:40 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
Informazioni: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
mag 11, 2014 7:06:40 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
Informazioni: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
mag 11, 2014 7:06:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
Informazioni: Initialization processed in 4344 ms
mag 11, 2014 7:06:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
Informazioni: Starting service Catalina
mag 11, 2014 7:06:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
Informazioni: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
mag 11, 2014 7:06:42 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
Informazioni: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [343] milliseconds.
mag 11, 2014 7:06:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
Grave: Exception starting filter struts2
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:527)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:509)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4775)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5452)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

mag 11, 2014 7:06:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
Grave: Error filterStart
mag 11, 2014 7:06:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
Grave: Context [/Struts2Starter] startup failed due to previous errors
mag 11, 2014 7:06:43 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
Informazioni: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
mag 11, 2014 7:06:43 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
Informazioni: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
mag 11, 2014 7:06:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
Informazioni: Server startup in 2882 ms
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19985547/573032

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16883428/573032

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22617924/573032

Comment: @RomanC: Doesn't work.

Comment: Did you do that in those answers? What is the error?

Comment: @RomanC: yes, I removed the jar file from the library but I get another error. See the edited question.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case to anyone that have same problem. change java version to 1.7 or higher at project facet.

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
```

means that `struts2-core.x.x.x.jar` should be on classpath, e.g. in the `WEB-INF/lib`.

Comment: Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/C:/Users/Dario/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Struts2Starter/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-portlet-plugin-2.3.16.3.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:31:133

Answer (score 0):

You are currently loading S2 plugins for which you do not have the required dependencies.

You're missing dependencies.

1. Only deploy S2 plugins you're actually using.
2. Include the dependencies for the plugins you're actually using.
3. You still need the S2 libraries and their dependencies for anything to work at all.

This is one reason why you should consider using a dependency management tool like Maven, Gradle, Ivy, etc. Tracking transitive dependencies manually is unpleasant at best.